# Changing all links in google chrome using javascript console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, automation, console

I am reading the research papers from NeurIPS conference, but if you click on any research paper it opens a new page and then you have to select pdf option to open the paper. So basically it's three steps process. But I am trying to make it a two-step process by changing source code via console.

This is the [conference website url](https://papers.nips.cc/book/advances-in-neural-information-processing-systems-32-2019), Now if you click on any link , for example the first paper link url it looks like this :

> https://papers.nips.cc/paper/8296-multimodal-model-agnostic-meta-learning-via-task-aware-modulation

But if you add '.pdf' at last of this url, it opens up the pdf directly

> https://papers.nips.cc/paper/8296-multimodal-model-agnostic-meta-learning-via-task-aware-modulation.pdf

What I am trying to do is, a console script which adds '.pdf' in all href so I don't have to go through the paper page and then pdf

I tried to collect all the URL from the website :

```
var urls = [];
for(var i = document.links.length; i --> 0;)
    if(document.links[i].hostname === location.hostname)
        urls.push(document.links[i].href);
```

How to change all URL and add '.pdf' at last so when I click any link on website URL it will go directly to pdf URL?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(x => x.href = `${x.href}.pdf`)
```

Like this? This will add ".pdf" to all links on the document so if you want to exclude something you can use Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).filter(< FILTER YOUR LINKS >) or if possible you can also just change the css selector!

Comment: Exactly, What I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What is the desired result? Do you just want a list of links with ".pdf" appended to each, or do you want to change the links themselves so when you click on them, they already have ".pdf" appended?

If the former, this will return an array of the links with .pdf appended:

```
var urls = [];
for(var i = document.links.length; i-- > 0;)
    if(document.links[i].hostname === location.hostname)
        urls.push(document.links[i].href += '.pdf');
```

If the latter, this will append .pdf to all the links on the page:

```
var urls = [];
for(var i = document.links.length; i-- > 0;)
    if(document.links[i].hostname === location.hostname)
        document.links[i].href += '.pdf';
```